# How to override the standard page only for specific record Type?

Tags: apex, visualforce, record-type, tasks

I have a new custom VF page for the button `Log a call` but I want to use this page only when user selects the General Inquiry for everything else it should go to standard page.

How do I do this?

Below are screenshots on what I am talking about:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**

I tried the below code but looks like it is in a infinite loop:

VF page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" 
            standardController="TASK" tabStyle="Task" 
            extensions="TaskVFPageExtension" action="{!urlRedirect}">
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference urlRedirect() {
    String selectedRecordType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType');

    Id recTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Task.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('General Inquiry').getRecordTypeId();

    if(String.valueOf(recTypeId) != selectedRecordType){
        PageReference currentPage = ApexPages.currentPage();
        currentPage.getParameters().put('nooverride','1');
        currentPage.setRedirect(true);
        return currentPage;
    }else{
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Override the Log a call button to take to a VF page, controller checks for record type via page action method and if should go to standard, redirects using the nooverride=1 parameter, otherwise stay on the vf page

Comment: @Eric I tried the above code(edited the question)..Could you please let me know what is wrong with this code?

Comment: @Eric , Nevermind..I figured out how to get query parameters from the current URL and prepare a new URL and add the parameter `nooverride=1`..Thanks for the idea on how to solve this.

Comment: Ok, posted as an answer so you can accept and the question does not keep surfacing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the Log a call button to take to a VF page, controller checks for record type via page action method and if should go to standard, redirects using the nooverride=1 parameter, otherwise stay on the vf page